# Code for Inherit design

Tags: c#

I want to write application that takes `Wireshark File` and read all the packets inside this file.
So i want to able to support several formats.
Until now i can handle Libpcap, Pcapng and TcpDump.
So i wonder hot to design my application.
I was thinking  to create abstract class:

```
 public abstract class WiresharkFile
    {
        private string _fileName;
        private int _packets;
        private string _duration;
        protected abstract IEnumerable<Packet> ReadPackets(string file);
    }
```

As you can see all the formats that inherit from this `WiresharkFile` have name, packet (each file contain several packets and duration).
And also `ReadPackets` method because every format need to read the file in other way.
So my question is in case i am choose file and want to read it's packets how can i know what the file format in order to run the correct `ReadPackets` method that i have for each format.

Comment: Is your problem to determine the type from the file? How do you distinguish them "manually"? By a suffix in the file name? By a special code at the beginning of the file?

Comment: prefix, x bytes at the beginning of the file.

Comment: I like the [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) for this using interfaces instead of an abstract class for the file format reader. A factory pattern could still be used to keep the strategy choice outside of whatever component is processing the packets.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is a [Factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). In the most simple form, that is just a static method like

```
public abstract class WiresharkFile
{
     public static WiresharkFile WiresharkFileFactory(string filename)
     {
     //  ... logic here to create either a LibpcapWireSharkFile, a 
     //  ... PcapngWireSharkFile, or another subclass instance
     }
}
```

If that method has a certain complexity, you may consider to move that method out of the `WiresharkFile` class to a separate factory class. And if you need those classes in an extensible library, where you can add new derivations afterwards without changing the factory code, you may have a look into the [abstract factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern).

Note that when your factory creates the object, you can already pass the filename to that object, so your `ReadPackets()` methods should not need any `filename` parameter any more.

Comment: So inside this i am just do WiresharkFile = new LibpcapWireSharkFile()...

Comment: @markyer: yes, but you obviously have to add some logic to determine which subclass is the correct one.